# How to convert Latitude and longitude to float value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have tried the below code :
 but it shows error cannot convert value of type float to expected argument type CLLocation degrees(aka Double)

```
    let lat = self.mallData.valueForKey("lat") as! Float
    let lon = self.mallData.valueForKey("lon")



    let mapLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
```

Comment: lat and lon are strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` supports `Double` values. But you are converting `lat` and `lon` to `Float`.

Try converting `Lat` and `Lon` to `Double`.

Answer (score -3):

Please check this answer

```
    let lat = self.mallData.valueForKey("lat")
    let lon = self.mallData.valueForKey("lon")

    let latDoubleValue = lat?.doubleValue
    let longDoubleValue = lon?.doubleValue
    let locationCoord : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDoubleValue!, longDoubleValue!)
```